How are the hyperreals totally disconnected
I understand that the rationals are totally disconnected by the fact, that they can form a pair of open sets with an irrational bound whose union is all of $\mathbb Q$. I also see that the hyperreals are disconnected into halos of real numbers and unlimited galaxies. But inside the halo of zero the infinitesimals are a miniature version of the reals such that $(-\infty, \varepsilon)$ and $(\varepsilon, \infty)$ both do not contain the infinitesimal $\varepsilon$ and hence their union is $*\mathbb{R}\setminus\{\varepsilon\}$. So $*\mathbb{R}$ is not disconnected everywhere?

Please provide some sources for your claims.

Does the fact that $\mathbb{Q}=(-\infty,2)\mathbb{Q}\sqcup(2,\infty)\mathbb{Q}\sqcup{2}$ mean that $\mathbb{Q}$ isn't totally disconnected?

You won't get disconnectedness using internal sets like $(-\infty, \epsilon)$. But consider the union of the sets $(-\infty,n\epsilon)$ as $n$ ranges over the standard natural numbers.
